# How to toggle SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION after interaction?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag in an activity to hide the system bar (I'm working on a "kiosk" style application)

It works really well, but any kind of interaction makes it re-appear, as the documentation states.

What would be the best way to re-enable this flag after any interaction?

Could anyone point me in a good direction on how to implement an "auto-toggle"?

nb - I do not want to (in fact I cant, for the proejct) use 3rd party applications to achieve this feature.

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting?

Comment: API 15+ (its likely the app will only be on API 17+ but it needs to be 15+ just in case the devices change)

Comment: If the fullscreen aspect of your application can live in its own activity, you can simply add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to your manifest.

Comment: Ben - that only gives you a "fullscreen" theme. On a tablet UI, the system bar (that holds the home, menu and back buttons) is always present, even with a "fullscreen" theme (trust me, I've tried every combination!) because the user needs to be able to navigate still. The system flag I mentioned is the correct way to hide this bar, but I'm looking for the best implementation of it (auto-hide after x seconds, toggle on touch etc)

Comment: Got it, I didn't catch the tablet aspect of the app.  Sorry I can't be of more help on this one.

Comment: Any chance you solved this and can post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add "SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY" option for keep hiding.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html